# Why AlertDialog.Builder for custom layout (Tablelayout) showing half empty dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am using a custom layout in alertDialog, But the problem is that it is showing the content of my layout file in half screen while other half is just blank -(I don't know from where this black portion come), I want to remove the blank portion of dialog.

Any suggestion or help will be thankful.

My alterDialog code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(view);
```

Layout of dialog_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:text="SCAN ASSEMBLY"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Scan job"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lot_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2342wt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black_text_color" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Scan assembly"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="2342wt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black_text_color" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Job quantity"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lot_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="2342wt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black_text_color" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Prod. time (hrs)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="2342wt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black_text_color" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Prod. date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="2342wt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black_text_color" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Prod. shift"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shift_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2342wt"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black_text_color" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and the output is:
[image]

Comment: is your xml complete posted ?

Comment: yes, it's complete xml.... just ignore the text against textview

Comment: maybe because Your width attributes are set to wrap_content?

Comment: Must be because of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Thank you very much @Opiatefuchs for helping to related the problem related to wrap_content ... It's done :)

Comment: Thank you very much @ArtemChauzov for helping to related the problem related to wrap_content ... It's done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figure out the problem. Thanks Khizar and Arthem Chauzov for your helping comments.
I just did a small change, As `table layout` are inherited from `LinearLayout`. I just set `android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1"` for my contents of rows. And now it's working as required :)

Comment: Cheers ... Keep Coding

Comment: I am having a similar problem, could you possibly post your correct XML code in your answer?